# How to delete cross-related records

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

In a given table I have two records that are related to each other.  In the first a pointer points to the second, and in the second the pointer points to the first.  The requirement is to delete either, and by trigger action to delete the other.

I have tried deleting the second in the *after delete* trigger of the first record by using

```sql
Delete from table where key = <second record>
```

thinking that since this is *after delete* by the time the trigger runs for deletion of the second record, the first record would no longer exist. However the result is that neither record is deleted.

I have tried deleting the cross reference from the second record in the *before delete* trigger of the first record using

```sql
Update table set cross reference to 0 where key = <second record>
```

to stop the trigger having any affect when called the second time.  Still neither record is deleted.

It is as if the changes are not actually applied to the database until all actions have been recorded, hence the first approach fails because when the second trigger runs the first record *does* still exist, and in the second case the change to the second record is not applied by the time the second trigger runs.  Thank goodness Firebird recognises the un-implied loop and stops.

The script is over 2,000,000 lines and must have a thousand situations where a record is deleted, so please don't ask me to change the script.  I have googled this many times but all references to delete are either simple references or for multiple records known at the time the script is run.  And remember this is Firebird 2.5.

Does anybody know how to do this from the triggers?

```sql
Create table Tab (Tab_key integer not null primary key, Cross_ref integer);
Insert into Tab  (Tab_key, cross_ref) values (1,2);
Insert into Tab  (Tab_key, cross_ref) values (2,1);

Create trigger A_Delete for Tab After Delete 
as
begin
Delete from Tab where Cross_ref= old.Tab_Key;
end

Delete from Tab where Tab_Key = 1; /*Should delete both records*/
```

Must be a grey moment, I have just tried this simple example and it works. So my code is wrong or something else in my code is conflicting.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], that is the necessary DDL to create the table, inserts with example data, and the statements you tried and their errors if any. And provide *real* statements, not pseudo code.

Comment: In your simple example you forgot foreign key. That's why it works.

Comment: Please don't add things like *SOLVED* to a question. If you managed to solve your problem, post an **answer** describing/showing the solution in detail.

Comment: However, the code in your question: you shouldn't use a trigger like that, use a cascading foreign key constraint (i.e. foreign key ... on delete cascade).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately cascading action is done by auto-generated triggers so there should be no difference in regard to recursion depth limit.

Comment: Sorry Mark, this is the first question I have ever posted and was not sure what the protocol was.  I expected to find a "Solved" button and without it I was lost.

Comment: Also I had not realised that a forign key could point to its own table.

Comment: If there is an answer (either posted by someone else or you yourself), you can click the "Accept" button (the tick-symbol), which will essentially mark it as solved. So, post your answer with a solution, and accept it after the timeout (you can't immediately self-accept your own answer).